# Determine the inverse of the following function. Then state if the inverse is the a function.

Tags: functions

$$y=\frac{0.5}{3-2x} -4$$

I do not know how to find the inverse of the equation. I know that we have to interchange the $x$ and $y$, but I need somebody to show me the proper steps please.

Comment: Do you mean $$y=\frac{1}{2(3-2x)}-4$$

Comment: no, the 2 in front of the bracket is not there

Comment: it is y=1/3-2x -4

Comment: So it is $$y= \frac{1}{3-2x}-4$$

Comment: no it is (0.5/3-2x) -4

Comment: So it is $$y=\frac{0.5}{3-2x}-4$$?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: I had troubles finding the proper steps to find the inverse. All I know is to change the x and y, but i do not know how.

Comment: Isn't $0.5 = 1/2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$y = \frac{0.5}{3-2x}-4$$
By definition, any coordinate $(x, y)$ for $f(x)$ will be $(y, x)$ for $f^{-1}(x)$. Switch $x$ and $y$.
$$f^{-1}(x) \implies x = \frac{0.5}{3-2y}-4$$

Solve for $y$.

$$x+4 = \frac{0.5}{3-2y} \implies 3-2y = \frac{0.5}{x+4} \implies -2y = \frac{0.5}{x+4}-3$$

$$\implies y = -\frac{1}{2}\biggr(\frac{0.5}{x+4}-3\biggr) \implies y = \frac{1}{2}\biggr(3-\frac{0.5}{x+4}\biggr)$$

Comment: and how do we know if the inverse is a function? what steps are taken to figure this out.

Comment: No two values of $x$ result in the same output $y$.

Comment: so the inverse is basically interchanging the x and y correct?

Comment: Yes. You can also visualize this by taking a look at a few functions and their inverses on a graph. $f^{-1}(x)$ and $f(x)$ are “mirrored” along the diagonal line $y = x$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973745/608962

Comment: so this is correct? (check the link). by the way, thank you very much

Comment: one more thing, to prove that the inverse is not a function, would u just plug any 2 numbers into the equation to prove or not?

Comment: For your first question, yes, both answers are correct. For your second question, there are multiple ways of testing. You could either check $f^{-1}(x)$ and see if it meets the criteria for a function (vertical-line test or that). Or, you could check the original function to see if it passes the horizontal-line test. If it does, the inverse is fine. If not, the inverse isn’t a function. As I said, you can try checking the graphs of such functions to get a better idea of what’s going on.

Comment: Check the graph in the link. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/veggp3c1bb

Comment: so this equation is a function along with its inverse correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score 0):

Ok write $$y+4=\frac{0.5}{3-2x}$$ then we get

$$3-2x=\frac{0.5}{y+4}$$
so
$$3-\frac{0.5}{y+4}=2x$$
dividing by $2$:
$$x=\frac{1}{2}\left(3-\frac{0.5}{y+4}\right)$$
and you can write $$y=\frac{1}{2}\left(3-\frac{0.5}{x+4}\right)$$

Comment: what are the 2 x for??? and is this the inverse of the function?

Comment: Yes this is the inverse of the function

Comment: I have added $2x$ on both sides

Comment: on the last step, it says x= at the beginning and=x at the end. What does that mean.

Comment: This was a typo, sorry!

Comment: the answer above yours, says the exact opposite, with -1/2 and the fraction -3. Which one is correct?

Comment: My answer is correct, i have written each step for you!